# Adding custom defined objects to NSMutableArray overwrite the whole array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

```
-(id) initWithData:(NSString *)lastName: (NSString *)firstName{
self->firstname =  firstName;
self->lastname =  lastName;

return self;
}


-(void) printData {
NSLog(@"firstname: %@", firstname);
NSLog(@"lastname: %@", lastname);
}
```

so whenever I create a new object using the above init function. And Add objects to a NSMutableArray, using the addObject function.

```
NSMutableArray *objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CustomObject *tempObject = [[CustomObject alloc] initWithData: @"smith": @"john"];
CustomObject *tempObjectb = [[CustomObject alloc] initWithData: @"brown": @"william"];
[objectArray addObject:tempObject];
[objectArray addObject:tempObjectb];

[[objectArray objectAtIndex:0] printData];
[[objectArray objectAtIndex:1] printData];
```

objects at index 1, and 0 always equal the  whichever object was added to the array last.
This also happens if I use a for loop, or have more than 2 objects, all values when printed, turn to the values of the last added object to the objectArray. Let me know if there is any information that I am missing.
Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Try adding this into your `initWithData`: if ( self = [super init] { .. rest comes here .. } return self; }. I assume your custom object inherits from NSObject, therefore you have to call the [super init].

Comment: sorry, mistyped variable names.

Comment: ahh i'l try that, thanks iska.

Comment: You've also misused ->. Unless you really know what you're doing, you should almost never use -> for ObjC objects. You meant self.firstname=firstname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your `initWithData:lastName:` implementation as following:

```
-(id) initWithData:(NSString *)lastName: (NSString *)firstName
{

self = [super init];
if ( nil != self ) {
  self->firstname =  [firstName retain];
  self->lastname =  [lastName retain];
}

return self;
}
```